# VirtualBox: connecting two VMs with crossover cable

Tags: networking, virtualbox, crossover-cable

I want to connect two Windows PCs with cross over cable, but I have no *admin* account, i.e, I cannot configure the IP addresses in the Windows host OS's.

I was wondering if you could do it with **two virtual machines** (one in every PC). I know it's a weird scenario, but I just want to test whether is possible.

The problem is that once I connect the *crossover* cable, the host systems lose their IP's (I have no admin privileges in the Windows hosts to configure the network settings).

So, as I see it, no matter what type of network adapter I use in VirtualBox (bridge, nat, host-only, internal network) it won't allow me to connect both VM's through the crossover cable that is physically connected to the PC NIC's.

Is there any way in VirtualBox to achieve this?

Comment: I think this maybe a XY problem and you need to specify why you want to make that connection. If you did an internal network, you can figure them both with a class C address, and it would act as if it's connected directly via a crossover cable.

Comment: but I have the two VMs in two different hosts, they are not running on the same host.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood that bit. I wonder if Vbox under windows has any support for PCI Passthrough, as this is another way it might be possible?

Comment: @djsmiley2k I'll check that out, thanks. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do anything.

The 169.254.xx.xx address you get after a bit of trying to get any IP Address from a DHCP server works well with a cross-over cable.

So long story short, just connect the cable, let it "loose" that original ip address so both get a 169.254.xxx.xxx address and start networking.

Comment: ok, that's an apipa address. But if I would like to configure a C class private IP address, this wouldn't be possible, right?

Comment: You could install a DHCP server software on one of the computers, and let it assign an IP Address to the other computer. Otherwise no, you need admin privileges on both pc's, or hardware such as a router that does DHCP for you.